# Task variable ContinueWith, await later?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Consider the following Google sample code:

```
    private Task<IUploadProgress> UploadFileAsync(DriveService service)
    {
        var title = UploadFileName;
        if (title.LastIndexOf('\\') != -1)
        {
            title = title.Substring(title.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        }

        var uploadStream = new System.IO.FileStream(UploadFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
            System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        var insert = service.Files.Insert(new File { Title = title }, uploadStream, ContentType);

        insert.ChunkSize = FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload.MinimumChunkSize * 2;
        insert.ProgressChanged += Upload_ProgressChanged;
        insert.ResponseReceived += Upload_ResponseReceived;

        var task = insert.UploadAsync();

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // NotOnRanToCompletion - this code will be called if the upload fails
            Console.WriteLine("Upload Filed. " + t.Exception);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Closing the stream");
            uploadStream.Dispose();
            Logger.Debug("The stream was closed");
        });

        return task;
    }
```

I'm using part of the code in an **async** method.
I wonder if the following altered code is still correct with regards to the **var task**, **ContinueWith** and **await**.?

```
        var task = insert.UploadAsync();

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // NotOnRanToCompletion - this code will be called if the upload fails
            Console.WriteLine("Upload Filed. " + t.Exception);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Logger.Debug("Closing the stream");
            uploadStream.Dispose();
            Logger.Debug("The stream was closed");
        });

        await task;

        if (task.Result.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
        {
```

I get compilation warnings at the ContinueWith statements.

Comment: what warnings do you get?

Comment: @NedStoyanov "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `ContinueWith` when you are using `await`, the rest of the method gets automatically registered as a continuation. You should be able to just do:

```
 try
 { 
    var result = await insert.UploadAsync();
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Upload Filed. " + ex.Message);
 }
 finally
 {
     Logger.Debug("Closing the stream");
     uploadStream.Dispose();
     Logger.Debug("The stream was closed");
 }
```

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) explains a bit more about `async\await`

Comment: That's pretty obvious now when looking at your code. :)
Thank you!